# i have problem how to make a htaccess with these example

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

for example
`webku.com/index.php?src=admin&mod=login&year=2022`

and the result i am desired is `webku.com/2022/index.php?src=admin&mod=login`

which is from the question is how to pass the parameter of year = 2022 into the beginning of script file position.

Comment: What you have tried till now ?Also share the code .

Answer (score 0):

This should generally be what you ask for. But your question is vague an general, so you will have to adapt it to your specific situation, which we can't guess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(\d+)/index\.php?year=$1 [QSA,L]
```

You can implement such a rule in the http server's host configuration. Or, if you do not have access to that, you can use a *distributed* configuration file (".htaccess") located in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder of your http host